# HTML, CSS верстка блоков, помогите пожалуйста расположить блоки как на картинке

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

```css
.allBlock {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #12ffa8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 650px;
  height: auto;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="allBlock">

  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <h3 class="h3">Текст</h3>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <h3 class="h3">Текст</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <h3 class="h3">Текст</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста как разместить блоки как показано на картинке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Больно читать такие вопросы. Как вы дальше развиваться будете, когда 1+1 уже трудности вызывают?..

Comment: Да, что-то не могу сообразить в данном вопросе. У меня основной акцент на бекенд и занимаюсь спрингом сейчас.

Comment: Акцент не мешает знать элементарные вещи, как блоки, выравнивание и т.п., как и фронтендер должен знать основу бека (хотя бы как сервер работает), имхо.. Раз вы бекендер то и гуглить уметь должны уже. "css выравнивание блоков" какое-то попробуйте загуглить, а лучше уделите пол часа на "изучение" флекса, с вас не убудет, но в дальнейшем не будете такие вопросы задавать

Comment: Флекс значит. Понял, сверстал. И за такие комментарии спасибо. Сообразил что к чему.

Comment: Не было намерений оскорбить. Но дело ведь 5-ти минут) Можете удалить свой вопрос т.к. он, по сути, бесполезный и не несёт никакой пользы. А можете и не удалять, дело ваше. Удачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 15px;
  grid-row-gap: 15px;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  background: #8be8c3;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  background: #e88b8b;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  background: #ad8be8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> 1 </div>
  <div class="div2"> 2 </div>
  <div class="div3"> 3 </div>
</div>
```